# How to hide and show scenes using three.js

Tags: three.js

I am creating scene using Three.js webgl library. I am having a texture in the first scene. Clicking on this texture, i am trying to navigate to the next scene. I have written a function to handle this scenario to move to the next scene. Clicking on this texture, it is moving to the second scene as expected, but it shows on top of the first scene. So, i would like to know How to programmatically show or hide scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
function setVisibility (parent, node)
{
    node.visible = parent.visible;
}

function traverseVisibility (parent, callback)
{
    var child, i, num_children = parent.children.length;

    for (i = num_children - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        child = parent.children[i];
        callback (parent, child);
        traverseVisibility (child, callback);
    }
}

yourNode.visible = false; // or true

traverseVisibility (yourNode, setVisibility);
```

Comment: what does this parent and node means here?

Comment: I think that the code is pretty obvious. Traceback who calls setvisibility and traverseVisibility. Look at the last line of the listed code. Parent is the node (or scene) that you would like to hide.

Comment: I assume you applied this on scene1? Can you show some code on scene creation and renderer calls?

Comment: At the beginning of scene2 i have given this code and followed by scene2 creation.Could i get sample code of this somewhere.

Comment: Here is the link where i have given my coding.please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361463/how-to-hide-or-show-scene-in-three-js